# DynamoDB read item by multiple attributes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am trying to design a dynamo table for storing Address information for a user. The actual user object is stored in a different place. One user can have multiple addresses.

So the User schema lookes something like below. Note only the unique user keys are needs to be here no real user data.

```
User
{
    userName
    email
}
```

And the schema for Address object is something like:

```
Address
{
    id // an unique id for address essentialy for all records in table
    attributes // other attributes related to address
}
```

How to efficiently design for below read access pattern:

1. Get address by ID
2. Get all addresses by userName
3. Get all addresses by email

And write access pattern is always by Address id. The write is not always only on adress attributes but often a change on associated user.

How to handle the scenarion if in future there is another user id type e.g. social security number introduced and it requires to retrieve all addresses by the new user id type (social security number)?

Analysis done so far:

Partition key: userName
Sort key: Address id

And a Global secondary index on

Partition key: email
Sort key: Address id

Answer (score 0):

`Get all addresses by user-id-1`

`Get all addresses by user-id-2`

| pk | sk | attributes | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user-id-1 | address-id-1 | attributes | user-1@examople.com |
| user-id-1 | address-id-2 | attributes | user-1@examople.com |
| user-id-2 | address-id-3 | attributes | user-2@examople.com |
| user-id-2 | address-id-3 | attributes | user-2@examople.com |

The a GSI to reverse keys

`Get address by ID`

| gsipk | gsisk | attributes | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| address-id-1 | user-id-1 | attributes | user-1@examople.com |
| address-id-2 | user-id-1 | attributes | user-1@examople.com |
| address-id-3 | user-id-2 | attributes | user-2@examople.com |
| address-id-3 | user-id-2 | attributes | user-2@examople.com |

Comment: I explained it wrong. I will edit the question and fix it. What I meant is "get all addresses either by userName or the email"

Comment: Then simply create another index and email as the key.